# Ruby gem Stream API like twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there any gem for ruby (I want to use it in a rails app) that does something like Twitter Stream API. Keep the http conection open and send information in real time basis, in a query or events.

Answer (score 3):

You need:

- a server that speaks HTTP in order to
  be able to understand queries and
  respond valid HTTP to the client
- an asynchronous system that will push
  updates in the connection established
  with the client when there's new data
  available.

Then [thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) is an options you might consider, it has a builtin http parser for the first requirement, and eventmachine for the second.

Have a look at this [example](http://github.com/macournoyer/thin/blob/master/example/async_tailer.ru) (run it with thin --rackup async_tailer.ru start). It is tailing asynchronously the /var/log/syslog through a open http connection. You can adapt this example to send data from other asynchronous sources from which you would like data to come.

Answer (score 1):

I think [twitter-stream](http://github.com/voloko/twitter-stream) should do what you want.

Comment: this is a client for the twitter stream api, i think the questionner is asking how to implement a similar service.

Answer (score 0):

[twitterstream](https://rubygems.org/gems/tweetstream) gem worked best for me

Answer (score 0):

[Twitter](https://github.com/sferik/twitter)  Gem has added streaming functionality.
you can check that out